# Employee Management System in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and working in Employee management system . I have created few classes including Employee(name, dob etc), Department (dept name, description etc). I have a requirement that Department must have 2 empoyee and less than 10.
Can anyone tell me how to make that association?
Department class:

```
public class Department {
    private String departmentName;
    private String locationofDep;
Employee emp = new Employee()


Getter.. setter
}

public class Employee {
        private String empName;
        private String dob;


    Getter.. setter
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Can you show me your source code which you have tried?

Comment: It seems you thought I'm the down voter. No. I just commented :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the question you should have a `collection` of `Employee` object. So you have to create `Employee` `Collection` such `List`, `Set` and etc. However you cannot limit the capacity a `Collection` such between two values. Programmatically only thing you can do is `throw` an `Exception` when calling the getter method of the `Collection`. You can put two default value to the `Collection`. I don't believe that would work for you. Do following modifications in your code.

```
public class Department {

    private String departmentName;
    private String locationofDep;
    //collection of empleyees
    Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

    //use this method to add employees
    public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        this.employees.add(employee);;
    }

    public Set<Employee> getEmployees() throws Exception {
        if (this.employees.size() < 2 || this.employees.size() > 10) {
            throw new Exception("Employees out of capacity");
        }

        return this.employees;
    }

    //other getters and setters should be here
}

public class Employee {

    private String empName;
    private String dob;

    //put getters and setters
}
```

So you can manage the employee length problem when you getting employee information using `try-catch` blocks